# Difference between HashSet.IsSuperSetOf and IsProperSuperSetOf?

Tags: c#, hashset

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb346923%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) documentation of both methods looks very similar.  Also the example cited beneath the remarks for `IsSupersetOf` is not very helpful either.

Can someone please explain to me the difference using simple language?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset

Comment: Good old math.  Amazing how one quickly forgets stuff that is not used on a daily basis.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can think of it like the difference between `>` and `>=`.  IsSuperSetOf is doing something like `>=`, so your set could have exactly the same elements that are in the set you're comparing to.  By contrast, a proper super set is kind of like `>` and has extra elements that the second set doesn't have.

For example, a set is a superset of itself, but it's not a *proper* superset of itself.

Comment: Thanks for the simplification.

Answer (score 9):

A superset of set `A` is a set that contains all of the elements of set `A`

A *proper* superset of `A` is a set that contains all of the elements of `A` but *is not equal to* `A`.

So if `A` = `{1,2,3}`, then `{1,2,3}` is a *superset* of `A` but not a *proper superset*, while `{1,2,3,4}` is a *proper superset*.

Answer (score 5):

A proper subset cannot equal the set.

{1,2,3} is a subset of {1,2,3}, but not a proper subset

{1,2} is a proper subset (and subset) of {1,2,3}

http://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/sets-introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the mathematical definitions underneath:

If A and B are sets and every element of A is also an element of B, then:

- B is a **superset** of (or includes) A, denoted by B ⊇ A.

If A is a subset of B, but A is not equal to B (i.e. there exists at least one element of B which is not an element of A), then

- B is a **proper superset** of A; this is written as B ⊋ A.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset)